# overiding default back navigation within activity with multiple fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

So i have a working solution, it seems not to be ideal but just need to confirm - so i have an activity with 3 fragments showing one at a time - i need to block the default back operation for two of those fragments so that when the back button is pressed nothing happens(for now, still developing).

So what i did was that i used an interface

```
//top of activity snippet
public class StudyKitActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnStudyKitBackListener{
private int fragment_id;
 .
 .
 .
 .
//interface method
@Override
public void onBackChanged(int fragment_id) {
    this.fragment_id = fragment_id;
}
```

to set a variable on the activity
 when i am changing the current fragment in the activity e.g set 1 for fragment A,  2 for fragment B and 3 for fragment C, so this is code snippet within fragment 2 when moving to fragment 3  -

```
  onStudyKitBackListener.onBackChanged(3);
    StudyKitResultFragment studyKitResultFragment =   StudyKitResultFragment.getInstance(examResult);
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, studyKitResultFragment).addToBackStack("exam_result").commit();
```

and i did an overwrite in my activity's onBackpressed to check the value of that variable and either execute the default OnBackPressed or do nothing like so -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(this.fragment_id==2||this.fragment_id==3){

    }
    else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

i came up with this cos other solutions like setting a tag and trying to get the fragment's tag or by checking current fragments id did not work for me,  this is working like i expected but i have not seen it anywhere just want to know if there is an alternate solution.

Comment: So,  your solution works  you are expecting some other solution .right?